# How to control a subthread process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

Code first:

```
'''this is main structure of my program'''

from twisted.web import http
from twisted.protocols import basic
import threading

threadstop = False    #thread trigger,to be done
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if threadstop:
                return
            dosomething()


'''def some function'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    t = MyThread()
    reactor.listenTCP(serverport,myHttpFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

As my first multithread program,I feel happy that it works as expected. But now I find I cannot control it. If I run it on front,Control+C can only stop the main process, and I can still find it in processlist; if I run it in background,I have to use `kill -9 pid` to stop  it. And I wonder if there's a way to control the subthread  process by a trigger variable, or a better way to stop the whole process other than `kill -9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html?highlight=atexit#module-atexit) module to register (in the main thread) a function that set the global `threadstop` to `True`, or, more simply, set the [daemon](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html?highlight=daemon#threading.Thread.daemon) attribute of the thread object to `True` so it won't keep the process alive if the main thread exits.

Comment: @SpawnCxy, glad to hear this!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question and Alex has already addressed your query, but here's a thought.

I see you're using python's `threading`. Did you try using `twisted.internet.threads` ?

When I find myself using threads in a `twisted` application, I go to `twisted.internet.threads`

Comment: As a newbie of python and twisted, i'm not familiar with this framework yet.And I'll check this class,thank you:)